# How to know whether liked the post or not without doing searching in the list

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I tried to use the fql query to get json response,I used this code for doing this

```
   String postid=jsonObject.getString("id");

   String query = "SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = \'" + postid + "'";

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
   params.putString("method", "fql.query");
    params.putString("query", query);

   String fqlResponse = Utility.mFacebook.request(params);

   System.out.println(fqlResponse);
```

But I am getting null pointer exception at Utility.mFacebook.request(params);

I am using the default class in Github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally find the Facebook Graph API a little inadequate at times. For example, in your current requirement, if you need to use just the Graph API, you will need to first, get a list of all Users who have liked a particular post. After you have a list, you will then have to check if the User ID matches that of the logged in User and then, based on the result, run a function or something.

Instead, FQL offers a simpler function. In my app, for the exact same function, I exclusively make use of FQL.

You can fire a simple query. For example:

```
SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id ='XXXXXXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXXX'
```

Replace the X's with the Post's ID. Make sure you surround the Post ID with **'YOUR_POST_ID'**

Try it like this in the Graph API Explorer: `fql?q=SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'ENTER_YOUR_POST_ID'`

After running the query, you should get a result that looks this this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "likes": {
        "user_likes": true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

If the User likes the Post, the field `user_likes` will be *true* and *false* if the User has not liked the Post.

You can parse the result like this (pseudo code):

```
if (JOLikeStatus.has("likes")) {
    JSONObject optLikes = JOLikeStatus.optJSONObject("likes");

    if (optLikes.has("user_likes")) {
        String getUserLikes = optLikes.getString("user_likes");

        if (getUserLikes.equals("true")) {
            String getLikeStatus = "true";
        } else if (getUserLikes.equals("false")) {
            String getLikeStatus = "false";
        }
    } else {
        String getLikeStatus = null;
    }
} else {
    String getLikeStatus = null;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** To get the number (count) of total likes, modify the earlier query like this:
`fql?q=SELECT likes.user_likes, likes.count FROM stream WHERE post_id = 'ENTER_YOUR_POST_ID'`

Comment: Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '100000845850045_495772590444719' I amgetting this error when I test in graph api explorer

Comment: @user1761316: Are you appending **fql?q=** before the `SELECT` query?

Comment: yes,I got json response as output.So,how to get whether user liked it or not.

Comment: @user1761316: Check the edit. I have added how the result looks along with some pseudo code.

Comment: Thanks for reply,I also have one more doubt,when I used like button in my application,how can I get the like count that instantly as android facebook app does.

Comment: @user1761316: Check the new edit. I am adding info for that in it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19946/discussion-between-user1761316-and-siddharth-lele)