# user Like status using fql query

Tags: android

I am using the following query to get the user like status

```
     fql?q=SELECT  likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE  post_id = '1274834235_3976149403543'
```

I expect the result to be

```
             {
          "data": [
                 {
                     "likes": {

                     "user_likes": false
                              }
                        }
                     ]
                   }
```

but I am getting like this

```
            {
               "data": [
                      ]
               }
```

I didnt know why I am getting like this.Did I need to add anything?

Help me,Thanks in advance

Comment: fql?q=SELECT  likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE  post_id = '100001532181088_102997539868287'  I changed to this but still getting same output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT  likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE  post_id = '80329313253_10151282619473254'

by adding friends_likes Permission

it returns

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "likes": {
        "user_likes": false
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: yes I added by clicking getAccessToken and I got permissions but still I am getting same error.could you please explain how you got

Comment: Are you sure that post_id = '1274834235_3976149403543' is alive ? Because i tried 5 or more different post_id's it works. Only your post id returns null

Comment: yes I got it now but,how did you know how to get response by using the android coding and I think need not to add any permissions in my coding

Comment: I couldnt understand what you mean ? sorry :)

Comment: I got json response now in graph explorer,how can I execute and get response in my android coding.

Answer (score 0):

Hi tried and it works for me, refer below

When i try to get your post_id,object_id  i recognized that all post_id is empty but facebook gives an object_id for post. (screenshoot1)

```
SELECT  object_id, post_id FROM like WHERE user_id=me()
```

then i tried to get likes for an object_id (screenshoot2 and screenshoot3)

```
SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE object_id="object_id"
```

and it returns user list who liked the post. So you can get the total user count from response.

**Screenshoot1**

[image]

**Screenshoot2**

[image]

**Screenshoot3 (direct get method)*

[image]

Comment: fql?q=SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream WHERE post_id = '100001532181088_102997539868287' I changed to this but still getting same output

Comment: try this without where fql?q=SELECT likes.user_likes FROM stream

Comment: I am just trying to get json response whether user liked the post or not

Comment: yes I tried in opengraph explorer,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514972/how-to-know-whether-liked-the-post-or-not-without-doing-searching-in-the-list/13515354#13515354       In this post I got the query and you can also see the output of query but when I tried in graph explorer it is returning empty array,did I need to add any permissions

Comment: I edited my answer, it works different way for me.  add read_stream permission

Comment: I am not trying to get the members who liked the post.I gave a link to you in that it is clearly mentioned if I use that query I should get user_likes field

Comment: So you want to check if a user liked a post or not ?

Comment: yes,but not by searching in the list .I think we can get directly as I show you by using the query I mentioned before.I am doing some mistake there,I really cant find that and now I am getting (Some of the aliases you requested do not exist:  fql) this error now

Comment: I see, but when i try your code. It always return null. Somebodys say facebook doesnt allow ? it can be true, matbe facebook resitriced getting likes directly ??

Comment: no,its possible by the query I gave you but I dont know why its not working